# ASP Page and COM component debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, com, asp-classic

I have website that has ASP pages and ASP.NET pages. The ASP page is using COM components which are registered in the machine.

I am currently using the website in Visual Studio 2008.

However, I am unable to debug into the VB(COM) code.

How to debug the COM code? I have not worked in COM.

I sincerely appreciate your input.

Comment: This might help - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/09/254602.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to debug a "in process" COM component (a COM hosted in a DLL) you can either start, or attach to, the executable that hosts the COM component from within the debugger and set breakpoints in your code.

For more information on how to do this using VB6 check here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299633

Hope this helps